# Dataset to chart 3 columns

Tags: c#, charts, dataset

I'm currently writing an application to show me a chart which shows data from a dataset.

The dataset contains 4 columns; a name, a timestamp, a value, inputrange

This has to do with measuring.

I have 3 different names currently in the dataset.

for example:

```
Sensor1, 23:00, 35, Celcius
Sensor2, 23:00, 32, Celcius
Sensor2, 24:00, 24, Celcius
Sensor3, 01:00, 28, Celcius
Sensor3, 02:00, 21, Celcius
Sensor3, 02:00, 21, Celcius
```

I need this data in a line chart. Whereas the name should be the "Series" from the Chart control. The Celcius column shouldn't be used.
Timestamp on X axis and values on the Y axis.

Is there any way to do this? anything that can point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Kinds regards

Comment: Check out https://www.google.com/#q=c-sharp+how+to+create+a+line+chart and https://www.google.com/#q=c-sharp+using+data+from+dataset - play with what you find, and if you get stuck on something specific, ask a questions, share your code and your particular problem and we'll help. Good luck.

Comment: Try to find and post an image that looks like what you want to achieve! 3 columns sound like 3 series. Think about the charttype and also about the scales if you want to show them  together..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The option I had to take was the DataBindCrossTable. This created series for each unique value in a certain column.

Comment: To make this  really usefull answer, please post the relevant code and also the result!